# how to send a value to asp textbox from AJAX success function....?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ClaretExamSchedule.aspx/LoadFatherInfo",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ appId: appId }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                       **I want to pass the return values here to ASP Textboxes**
                    }
                });
```

Given the code above, I passed a parameter for codebehind the method LoadFatherInfo, now 
I returned an ArrayList and I want every datum to be displayed using textbox.. Sorry for my English but I hope you get my point, any help will be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: sorry for the tag asp-classic .. it always happens to me. I always tag ASP only but when i post my question, i always see asp-classic... a stackoverflow bug most probably

Comment: Its not a bug.  ASP has been around for a very long time.  Most people understand the term "ASP" to specifically mean the older "classic" form based on COM and VBScript.  Hence stackoverflow has a synonym set up so that the tag "asp" is recognized as "asp-classic".  You are most likely using ASP.NET so you should use the tag "asp.net" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text boxes and web method will something similar to the code below:

```
<input type="text" id="Father1" value="" class="father" />
<input type="text" id="Father2" value="" class="father" />
<input type="text" id="Father3" value="" class="father" />
```

```
   [WebMethod]
   public string[] LoadFatherInfo(appId appId)
   {
        // Do Stuff        
        var fatherInfo = new List();

        fatherInfo.Add("John");
        fatherInfo.Add("Jim");
        fatherInfo.Add("Joe");

        return fatherInfo.ToArray();
    }
```

you could change your ajax call to something similar to the javascript below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ClaretExamSchedule.aspx/LoadFatherInfo",                     
    data: JSON.stringify({ appId: appId }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: PopulateFatherBoxes,
    error: OnError
});


function PopulateFatherBoxes(data, status) {
    var i = 0;   
    $(".father").each(function() {
        $(this).val(data.d[i]);
        i++;
    });
}
```